# date validation failing in java

Tags: java, validation, date

I have the date validation code as below, it does not throw parseException for 01/01/19211.

What is the problem. Does anyone have alternate solution? I cannot use any third party libraries.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            resetPasswordUIBean.setDateOfBirth(dateFormat.parse(resetPasswordUIBean.getDateInput()));       
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            //handleException 
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Note to future readers: You should not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Use the modern Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package. [See Arvind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68293184/507738).

Comment: Note that the input string `01/01/1921blah` [does not cause](https://ideone.com/V1JIsE) a `ParseException` to be thrown either, despite the invalid substring "blah". That is because the parsing completes when all pattern letters have been consumed, regardless of whether the whole text has been parsed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem. It's accepting a valid date of the 1st of January 19211. I know it's not clear from the docs, but "yyyy" accepts more than 4 digits, for years beyond 9999.

If you want to restrict the date to some maximum year (e.g. not in the future, if this is meant to be a date of birth) then you can do so easily by finding out the year from the `Date` (via `Calendar`, of course). You probably want a minimum year as well. These are validation steps which make sense *separately* from parsing - basically there are plenty of dates which are valid *as dates* but aren't valid in your context.

Comment: The date format is yyyy so technically it should not accept 19211(yyyyy), correct?

Comment: @RegisteredUser: It's not clear from the docs, to be honest - but I think *typically* parsers handle more than four digits for `yyyy`, and this seems to be the case here. I think it's reasonable, in order to handle both the "normal" case of a year up to 9999, but *also* handle later dates. Read my edited answer - you'd want to add more validation *anyway*.

Comment: I hope they have not designed it thinking their code will be used in year > 10000 :)

Answer (score 1):

### A single `y` can parse the years of one+ digits

**Caution:** A two-digit year will be parsed as a year without a century e.g. `19` will be parsed as `0019`. If you want it to be `2019`, use `yy`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Stream.of(
                    "01/01/1",
                    "01/01/19",
                    "01/01/192",
                    "01/01/1921",
                    "01/01/19211"
        ).forEach( s -> System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0001-01-01
0019-01-01
0192-01-01
1921-01-01
+19211-01-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/AlL9yz)

Therefore, you need to get the value of the year from the resulting date and validate the year e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y", Locale.ENGLISH);
        int year = LocalDate.parse("01/01/19211", dtf).getYear();
        if (year < 1900 || year > 9999) {
            // Do this
        } else {
            // Do that
        }
    }
}
```

You may also like to check [prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>